# How can I graph an equation with five variables?

Tags: plotting

```
{c*((a - b*Cot θ)/(Subscript[r, 1])^4) + ((b*Csc θ)/(Subscript[r, 2])^4)
```

This is a form of Poiseuille's Law I need to graph. I want the value of the variables to be `c = 1, a = 10, b = 5, r1 = 1, r2 = 2/3`.

Answer (score 2):

I initially edited your question to improve formatting but I think that your problem is probably in regard to the way that code is written, so I restored the original.

1. Try to avoid using `Subscript`.  It often significantly complicates things.
2. Make sure you are using functions properly, e.g. `Csc[θ]`, not `Csc(θ)`

Now, please consider this:

```
expr := (c (a - b Cot[θ]))/r1^4 + (b Csc[θ])/r2^4;

Block[{c = 1, a = 10, b = 5, r1 = 1, r2 = 2/3},
  Plot[expr, {θ, 0, 10}]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I recommend

```
expr := Evaluate @ 
  With[{c = 1, a = 10, b = 5, r1 = 1, r2 = 2/3}, (c (a - b Cot[θ]))/r1^4 + (b Csc[θ])/r2^4]
```

This produces a compact form for `expr`.

```
OwnValues @ expr
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[expr] :> 10 - 5 Cot[θ] + (405 Csc[θ])/16}
> ```

And the `Plot` expression is simplified to

```
Plot[expr, {θ, 0, 10}]
```

[image: plot]

I believe this to be more robust and efficient than using `Block`, but perhaps Mr.Wizard will disabuse me of a misconception.

Comment: Different tools for different tasks.  I assumed that `expr` would be reused with different values.  Pre-evaluation is a nice alternative interpretation. +1